# How to design a logging event in python in an efficient way, rather than simply adding the events inside a function?

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns, event-handling

I want to implement the server-side event analytics feature (using https://segment.com/), I am clear in using the api, just we have to add the event api's inside a function whose action we need to monitor, for example, for creating a new user account in my application, I will have an event inside the function create_user

```
def create_user(email_id, name, id):
  # some code to add the user in my table
  ....
  ....
  # calling the segment api to track event
  analytics.track(user_id=email_id, event="Add User", properties={"username": name})
```

The above code works, but design wise I feel it can be done in a better way, since the create_user should have functionality of adding the user only, but here it contains the track event, and I have to do the same in modifying all the areas wherever I need to monitor by adding this analytics api and this makes my code contain irrelevant logic, I read about decorators but my analytics event depend on the code logic inside the function (like if the user email is valid then only I add the user to Db and trigger the event), so that doesn't seem to help.

So I am seeking help here in handling this scenario with the better approach and keeping the code clean. Is there any way or design approach exist for solving this case?

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this using decorators and one more separate function like below mentioned. With this code you have to call your confirm_loggin function based on the conditional event to log the data. While your inputs to the user function can be logged temporarily each time.

```py
def confirm_logging():
    '''
    Final logging function, where once called from the main function
    would log the data as need. Can be customized how it needs to be logged.
    '''
    global temp_log_data
    print("Finally logging the data", temp_log_data)
    # Can be taken ahead into DB logging.
    temp_log_data.clear()
    return

def logging_func(func):
    '''
    Temporary logging function for every function called into temp_log_data
    The below temporary logging mechanism can be customized as required
    '''
    global temp_log_data
    temp_log_data = []
    def wrapper_function(*args, **kwargs):
        # The below print statement can be customzied per your requirement
        # You can also call anyother function instead of print and use the args
        temp_log_data.append([args[0], args[1], args[2]])
        print("Temporary logging data here -", (args[0], args[1], args[2]))
        func(*args,  **kwargs)
    return wrapper_function

@logging_func
def create_user(greet, name, surname):
    '''
    Your main function, core to functionality specific
    '''
    print("{} {} {}".format(greet, name, surname))
    if name == 'Abhi':
        confirm_logging()
    return

create_user('Welcome', 'Abhi', 'Jain')
```

Comment: Hi Alonso, as mentioned above I can't trigger event directly after/before calling a function, it depends on certain conditions inside the function.

Comment: Yes, in the above greetings function can be your main function where you can define the condition and then only call the confirm logging function